# glib in cross compiling for raspberry pi c

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, glib

I'm trying to compile a program with glib. I set up all the include paths so compilation goes through without errors but linker can't find glib.

```
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/home/ja/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib -L/home/ja/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf  -o "daemon_test"  ./src/gpio/gpio.o  ./src/can/can_stuff.o ./src/can/libsocketcan.o  ./src/daemon_test.o   -lglib-2.0 -lwiringPi
/home/ja/raspberrypi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
makefile:32: recipe for target 'daemon_test' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [daemon_test] Error 1
```

I have a cross compiler set up for my raspberry pi. it's composed of eclipse and a gcc compiler running on debian.

it seems obvious that the linker can't find the proper file.
On my target raspberry pi I've installed libglib2.0-dev and a test program builds fine. So I used rsync to update my cross compiler's rootfs

```
rsync -rl --delete-after --safe-links pi@192.168.2.160:/{lib,usr,opt} $HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs
```

my include paths are set to the same values as come out from pkg-config on my rpi(adjusted for rootfs location)

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0
```

as I was writing this I did a search for "libglib" on both rpi and my cross compiler. there's a libglib-2.0.so on my rpi, but in my crosscompiler it's a libglib-2.0.so.0, they are both same size.

I removed the ".0" and got a new error

```
warning: libpcre.so.3, needed by /home/ja/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

and a bunch of undefined refferences. the thing is, that file exists in the same location as libglib-2.0.so(renamed form libglib-2.0.so.0)

```
-L/home/ja/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

anyone has any ideas what to do? I spent my whole day on this..

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?